# Problems changing properties on a control using the controls name

Tags: c#

This should work.. I think..

```
string ctrlName = "btnSomeButton" + someIndexValue;
this.Controls[ctrlName].Text = "Some value";
```

I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', the control does exist on the form. I've tried casting it.

Solution:

```
string ctrlName = "btnSomeButton" + someIndexValue;
Control[] ctrl = this.Controls.Find(ctrlName, True);
Button btn = (Button)ctrl[0];
btn.Text = "Some Value";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Test if ctrl[0] does exist *and* is a Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control might be a nested control so you're going to have to dig deeper in the control tree of "this"

Here is a simple recursive control search tool, i wrote it without testing it but i think it should work for your needs:

```
private Control FindControl(Control ctr, string name)
{
    Control c = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < ctr.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(ctr.Controls[i].ID, name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            c = ctr.Controls[i];
            break;
        }
        if (ctr.Controls[i].Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            c = FindControl(ctr.Controls[i], name);
            if (c != null)
                break;
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have a control named like `ctrlName` in your *immediate* `Controls` collection? It may be the name of a control that is deeper in the hierarchy, or even a control which doesn't exist.

Try finding the control recursively:

```
string ctrlName = "btnSomeButton" + someIndexValue;
Control[] matchingControls = this.Controls.Find(ctrlName, true);
foreach (Control c in matchingControls)
    c.Text = "Some value";
```

Comment: Okay I see what your are saying. The control (a button) is located on a tab control. I can see how this may be the problem. The only thing is that my form (or .this) has no 'FindControl' method. Why would that be?

Comment: There is only a FindControl in web forms. Regular Win forms don't have them. You can use this.Controls.Find(ctrlName, true); The "true" means that it should search all child controls as well. This should find your button.

Comment: A catch on my part: Controls.Find returns an array! So watch how you pull Controls out of it when it returns!

Answer (score 0):

Are your buttons actually controls on the form, or do they have a different parent? For instance, if you buttons reside inside a a `Panel` or `GroupBox` you will not be able to access them by name by just using `this`. You will need to find them in their container.

Example: `myPanel.Controls[ctrlName].Text = "Some Value"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the control methods in addition to this below to determine where the control is located i.e. what parent might have this control assigned.

```
 {
        Control[] ctls = this.Controls.Find("Button2", true);
        if (ctls.Length > 0)
        {
            Button btn = ctls[0] as Button;
            if (btn != null)
                btn.PerformClick();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button2 Clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you may want to consider creating a `Dictionary<string, Control>` collection that allows you to quickly refer to the control by name. This also frees you from requiring the control name containing the index.